# How to add associations via Sequelize Migrations to existing models in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have two existing models `user` and `permissions`. I would like to add one to many relationship to `user` model. I have been digging all the internet and there seems to be no documented way to achieve the same. Would someone point me in the right direction on how to write the migration scripts to perform the same? Thanks

Comment: which table is one, which is many? I think you can use alter table add foreign constrain (found on postgres doc)

Comment: User is one, Permission is many. A user can have as many permissions as possible

Comment: ALTER TABLE public.permissions ADD COLUMN "userId" VARCHAR (255), ADD FOREIGN KEY ("userId") REFERENCES public.user (id);

Comment: Read more at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676149/adding-a-column-as-a-foreign-key-gives-error-column-referenced-in-foreign-key-co

Comment: If you are using ORM, just use the way ORM suggest rather than this DSL query

Comment: Will this query create one to many relation?